# Why does rsyslog isequal filter fail?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I want to log everything from the `rsyslogd` executable (daemon) to a file.

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf
if $syslogtag isequal 'rsyslogd' then /tmp/foo.log 
if $syslogtag isequal 'rsyslogd:' then /tmp/foo.log
if $syslogtag isequal ' rsyslogd' then /tmp/foo.log
if $syslogtag isequal ' rsyslogd:' then /tmp/foo.log
```

In a separate shell:

```
sv down /root/service/rsyslog/
sv up /root/service/rsyslog/
tail -F /tmp/foo.log
```

Result: bupkus

So I edit `rsyslog.conf`:

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf
if $syslogtag contains 'rsyslogd' then /tmp/foo.log
```

Rinse and repeat; in a separate shell:

```
sv down /root/service/rsyslog/
sv up /root/service/rsyslog/
tail -F /tmp/foo.log
```

Tada: `20190424_195027 linuxbox info rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.28.0" x-pid="27384" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start`

What gives? I don't get why the attempts at using `isequals` fail.

The `%syslogtag%` *looks* like some variation of "rsyslogd" either with whitespace or a colon attached somewhere - but I think I've gone through every reasonable permutation thereof, so why is the `isequal` comparison failing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look for error messages during the parsing of your configuration  (for example with `rsyslogd -N1`), as your lines are being ignored. The `isequal` operator is used with this sort of syntax:

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "rsyslogd:"  ./output1
```

whereas the `if..then` syntax needs the `==` operator:

```
if $syslogtag == 'rsyslogd:' then ./output2
```

The `contains` operator works with both syntaxes.